# Disable ajax retry call

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Am develop a mobile app using jquery mobile, the next code makes a ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
timeout:ajaxTimeout,
url: url,
dataType: dataType,
data: {
    ···
},
success: function (response) { 
    ···
},
error: function(e, message){
    ···
},
complete: function(object, message){
    ···
}
});
```

From this call I receive a timeout, and automatically it makes a retry. How can I disable this retry call? I try use some parameters like `retryCount: 0, retryLimit: 10,` but it didn´t works

Comment: jQuery ajax has no built in `retry` functionality. This is something you are doing external to jQuery.